# error in LIKE SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using nodeJs and mysql package.

I want to use LIKE sql statement with varibale.

this is source code :

```
var likemobile = '%'+mobile;
var query = "SELECT vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid as 'leadid', 
                    vtiger_contactaddress.mobile,
                    vtiger_contactaddress.phone 
             FROM `vtiger_contactaddress` 
             INNER JOIN `vtiger_crmentity` 
                 ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid AND 
                    vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 AND 
                    vtiger_contactaddress.mobile LIKE "+likemobile+" OR 
                    vtiger_contactaddress.phone LIKE "+likemobile;
```

and this is error that returns:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%8
8436500 OR vtiger_leadaddress.phone LIKE %88436500' at line 1
```

Comment: It seems you have to wrap like condition with single quotes like this: "LIKE ' " + likemobile,  and close your query string with double quote. like this:  
" <...> LIKE "+likemobile + ";

Comment: @Alex can you show me how ?

Comment: @Alyreza can you try with below edit...as query should have '%8
8436500%' OR vtiger_leadaddress.phone LIKE '%88436500%' this  type of syntax.

Comment: @anwaar_hell error :     `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'
 OR vtiger_leadaddress.phone LIKE 88436500%'' at line 1`

Comment: you have executed by removing % from likemobile

Comment: here with % but : `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%8
8436500%' OR vtiger_leadaddress.phone LIKE %88436500%'' at line 1`

Comment: @Alyreza try now..as i have misplaced % and '.

Comment: First of all you have to understand what your query should look like purely - after applying concatenating. Then you should understand how concatenating works and what should you do to have the query you need.
I assume you need query like this: "select * from t where i like'%<condition>'".
and you have likemobile variable.
now let's build your query:
query = "select * from t where i like ' " + likemobile + " ' ";

Replace all specific values with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed are using `node-mysql`, you should run queries as instructed in [the documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#performing-queries). Assuming you have a `connection` object already, querying with bind variables becomes simple:

```
connection.query({
  sql : "SELECT vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid as leadid, "
                   + " vtiger_contactaddress.mobile, "
                   + " vtiger_contactaddress.phone "
             + "FROM `vtiger_contactaddress` "
             + "INNER JOIN `vtiger_crmentity` "
             + "  ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid"
             + " AND vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 AND "
             + "       (vtiger_contactaddress.mobile LIKE concat('%', ?) OR "
             + "       vtiger_contactaddress.phone LIKE concat('%', ?))",
  values: [mobile, mobile]
}, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

Things to note here:

- Bind variables are used, preventing [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- The [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function is used for prefixing the (sanitized) input with the wildcard character (`%`)
- The two query conditions that are `OR`ed together are now separated with parenthesis from `vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0`, which is probably what you want
- You need to write the resultset-handling code in the callback function, accessing the data through the `results` and `fields` variables

Answer (score 4):

You need to enclose the like pattern in single quotes.

Two other suggestions:

- Only use single quotes for string and date constants (not column aliases).
- Use parameterized queries, so you are not putting user input into query strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this..

         var likemobile = mobile;

var query = "SELECT vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid as 'leadid', 
                vtiger_contactaddress.mobile,
                vtiger_contactaddress.phone 
         FROM `vtiger_contactaddress` 
         INNER JOIN `vtiger_crmentity` 
             ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid AND 
                vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 AND 
                vtiger_contactaddress.mobile LIKE '% "+likemobile+"%'  OR 
                vtiger_contactaddress.phone LIKE '%"+likemobile +"%'";
```

Comment: nope, what is the differences ? in the question I predefined it. but I mine and yours does not work

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon Linoff is correct. Somelike this:

```
var likemobile = mobile;
var query = "SELECT vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid as 'leadid', vtiger_contactaddress.mobile, vtiger_contactaddress.phone FROM `vtiger_contactaddress` INNER JOIN `vtiger_crmentity` ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_contactaddress.contactaddressid AND vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 AND vtiger_contactaddress.mobile LIKE '%"+likemobile+"%' OR vtiger_contactaddress.phone LIKE '%"+likemobile+"%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... AND vtiger_contactaddress.mobile LIKE '%" + likemobile + "%' OR vtiger_contactaddress.phone LIKE %" + likemobile + "%";
```

Comment: nope, same error happen.`Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%8
8436500 OR vtiger_leadaddress.phone LIKE %88436500' at line 1`

Comment: edited, maybe quotes are not correct, I can't test it now ;-)